# Can't find `MainContentPlaceHolder` in Masterpage or returns NULL in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a class named `Alerts` which i inherit from `BootstrapPage`. I am using this class as a `MessageBox` to the users after doing some operation. Here is the code

```
public class BootstrapPage : Page
{
    public enum WarningType
    {
        Success,
        Info,
        Warning,
        Danger
    }

    public void ShowNotification(string message, WarningType type)
    {
        var mainContentHolder = Master.FindControl("MainContentPlaceHolder") as ContentPlaceHolder;
        Panel notificationPanel = new Panel();
        {
            LiteralControl closeButton = new LiteralControl();
            closeButton.Text = "<a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"close\">&times;</a>";

            Label notificationMessage = new Label() { Text = message };

            notificationPanel.Controls.Add(closeButton);
            notificationPanel.Controls.Add(notificationMessage);
        }
        notificationPanel.CssClass = string.Format("alert alert-{0} alert-dismissable", type.ToString().ToLower());
        notificationPanel.Attributes.Add("role", "alert");

        mainContentHolder.Controls.AddAt(0, notificationPanel);
    }
}
```

I have a `MasterPage` named `Site.Master` which is here (simplified code for better understanding)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="DeceasedSystem.Site" %>
```

and here is the `HTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
  <div class="col-md-9">
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the `contentPage`

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserProfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="DeceasedSystem.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Now when i logged in, it throws `NullReferenceException` on this line

```
            var mainContentHolder = Master.FindControl("MainContentPlaceHolder") as ContentPlaceHolder;
```

Here is the picture.
[image]

I have no clue why it throws `NullReferenceException`, when i have provided the `MainContentPlacholder` and it is present in my `MasterPage`. Please help me out because i don't understand the `Exception` and also what is the reason that it throws this `Exception`. 
**Note:** I am `Inheriting` web pages from `BootstrapPage`. Does this have anything to do with the `Exception`? Help me folks. PLEASE

Comment: By the looks of it, `ContentPlaceHolder` is what it cannot find

Comment: Yeah but it is there. then what is the problem that it can't find? Actually i have no idea that why it throws `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: What is it? Is it a class? Has it been defined above?

Comment: Yeah it is a `Class` named `Alerts`. I am doing this so that i don't have to use `Label` as a `Message`. You can check the the above `Class`.

Comment: Unless I can't see it, there is no class above called `Alerts`

Comment: The first `Code Snippet` in my question is the `Class Alerts`.

Comment: All I am seeing is an enum and then a method called `ShowNotification`. No class called `Alerts` before this.

Comment: My bad. The name of the file is `Alerts.cs`. sorry

Comment: This is the `Error` it throws. `Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'MainContentPlaceHolder' in the master page '/Site.Master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.`

Comment: The most suspicious part is this line: `MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"`. Do you have `Site.Master` file on the site root, or the master page is stored somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah it is on the `Site root`.